# Add "ON DELETE CASCADE" to existing column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I have user_id fk column in my table

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

I should add **on cascade delete** feature to this existing column. How can I do this?

Comment: use raw query `DB::statement('..')`. What is the name of your table?

Comment: name of the table is "answers"

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Drop foreign key first. Thanks to [Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3192276/razor) for this tip

```
$table->dropForeign('answers_user_id_foreign');
$table->foreign('user_id')
->references('id')->on('users')
->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: @BrentConnor If it is already migrated and in production, yes. Otherwise you can rollback the migration, edit the original file and then migrate again.

Comment: At least in laravel 5.7 in
$table->dropForeign('answers_user_id_foreign');
must be:
$table->dropForeign(['template_id']);

Comment: shorter and you dont need to know the naming convention when dropping the foreign key: $table->dropForeign(['user_id'])

Comment: What will happen to data on those columns or the table, if we will drop the foreign key?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu you are just dropping foreign key definition. You won't lose any data.

Comment: It's for up() method but what should require in  down() method for maintain rollback

Comment: tried on laravel 7 doest not work. I've to change `$table->dropForeign('answers_user_id_foreign');` to `$table->dropForeign('user_id');`

Comment: @AslamH Laravel generates foreign keys like following `{table_name}_{local_column}_foreign`. Unless you override it

Comment: Just a quick response to @MarcelGruber . Dont modify migrations, ever. Unless they are destroying data or doing something really harmful, migrations are meant to be a history of change to the db state, and when you change that history, it stops representing the state and things go bad. My rule of thumb is once its committed to git, its too late to edit, instead create a new migration.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, i'll need to put the col name in an array else that will be an error.

```
Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['transactions_order_id_foreign']);
    $table->foreign('order_id')
        ->references('id')->on('orders')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->change();
});
```

mysql 5.7 ver

Comment: $table->dropForeign(['tank_id']);
      $table->foreign('tank_id')->references('id')->on('tanks')->onDelete('cascade')->change();

Answer (score 7):

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                        
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'xxx.#sql-5d7_226' (errno: 121) (SQL: alter table `xxx` add constraint answers_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id  
  `) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: Then perhaps you should report it as a bug, because that is the official [documented method](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys)

Comment: OP was asking on how to add to an existing column, not how to create a new column with `onDelete`.

Answer (score 6):

Laravel schema builder can't modify columns at the current state, so you will use raw queries. You will have to drop and recreate the **constraint**:

**PostgreSQL**

```
function up()
{
    DB::statement('alter table answers drop constraint answers_user_id_foreign,
                   add constraint answers_user_id_foreign
                   foreign key (user_id)
                   references users(id)
                   on delete cascade;'
    );
}
function down()
{
    DB::statement('alter table answers drop constraint answers_user_id_foreign,
                   add constraint answers_user_id_foreign
                   foreign key (user_id)
                   references users(id);'
    );
}
```

**MySQL**

```
function up()
{
    DB::statement('alter table answers drop FOREIGN KEY answers_user_id_foreign;');
    DB::statement('alter table answers add constraint answers_user_id_foreign
                   foreign key (user_id)
                   references users(id)
                   on delete cascade;'
    );
}
function down()
{
    DB::statement('alter table answers drop FOREIGN KEY answers_user_id_foreign;');
    DB::statement('alter table answers add constraint answers_user_id_foreign
                   foreign key (user_id)
                   references users(id);'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for question answer. Help me get to this working code in L5.1 :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('transactions_order_id_foreign');
        $table->foreign('order_id')
            ->references('id')->on('orders')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->change();
    });

    Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('orders_user_id_foreign');
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->change();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the unsigned function to `user_id` in the present migration:

```
$table->interger('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('table_name')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 1):

As of `laravel 7.0` you can use `$table->foreignId('user_id');` it is an alias of `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');`

So our oneline solution to make the foreign key column delete cascade is as below:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();    
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

I am assuming you used `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::primary()` to create `users.id`. If that is the case, then `users.id` will be unsigned. Therefore your foreign key column `user_id` must also be unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Small code

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way to create of foreign key relationship

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

OR

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```