# Delete product_id from inventories table after deleting a group in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I want to delete the `product_id` in the inventories table after deleting a specific group.

Table Structure:

> **product_groups**
>      id | grp_name
>
> **products**
>     id | prod_name | price | group_id
>
> **inventories**
>     id | product_id | in_stock

Code:

```
public function ProductGroups_destroy($id)
{
    $product_group = ProductGroup::find($id);

    $product_group->delete();

    $product_group->product()->delete();

    $product_group->product->inventory()->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'Product group deleted');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Models

[Product Model, ProductGroup Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKQs0.jpg)

[Inventory Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFndH.jpg)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: (method inventory does not exist) After deleting a specific group, the products are deleted. but i also want to delete the product_id in the inventories table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use this in your Inventory Migration :

```
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Source : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

2) You can overwrite the delete method :

```
class Product extends Model {

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function inventory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Inventory', 'product_id');
    }

    public function delete()    
    {
        DB::transaction(function() 
        {
            $this->inventory()->delete();
            parent::delete();
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I have the following error on my migration "errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" (SQL: alter table 'inventories' add constraint 'inventories_product_id_foreign' foreign key<'product_id'> references 'products' <'id'> on delete cascade)                                                                  General error: 1005 cant create table. errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Comment: Try to write new migration with removal of foreign key first and then reassigning foreign key. Please check this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820788/add-on-delete-cascade-to-existing-column-in-laravel

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Cant drop 'product_id_foreign': check that column/key exists.. These are my tables, products -> |id|prod_name|group_id|. inventories  -> |id|product_id|instock|

Comment: I got it working.. but after deleting the group.. i got this error (Method inventory does not exist.). Controller Code:                                                           
public function ProductGroups_destroy($id)
    {
        $product_group = ProductGroup::find($id);
        $product_group->delete();
        $product_group->product()->delete();
        $product_group->product->inventory()->delete();

        Session::flash('success', 'Product group deleted');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

Comment: It worked.. using $product_group->product()->delete(); Thanks!